# NFA with k states to accept strings of length <=k

Tags: finite-automata

Is it possible to construct a NFA with k states that recognizes all strings of length <= k and reject all strings of length greater than k?

Answer (score 0):

No. The proof is by mathematical induction on `k`.

Base Case: for `k = 0`, a NFA with zero states is probably not even a valid object and certainly cannot be said to accept anything. Edit: probably worth adding `k = 1` as well, since the `k = 0` case is anomalous. For `k = 1`, either the state is not accepting (in which case the accepted language is empty) or it is accepting, in which case it either recognizes only the empty string (if no transitions which consume input are present) or infinitely many strings (if there are any transitions which consume input).

Induction hypothesis: assume for all `k` up to and including `n`, there is no NFA with `k` or fewer states accepting strings with length no more than `k` and rejecting strings with length greater than `k`.

Induction step: we must show there is no NFA with `k+1` or fewer states accepting strings with length no more than `k+1` and rejecting strings with length greater than `k+1`. Assume there were such a NFA. Consider the set of accepting states of this NFA. There must be at least one other than the initial state since the NFA accepts finitely many strings and more than just the empty string (see base case for k = 1). Furthermore, there must be some states in the NFA which can reach some of these other accepting states, since some input must be consumed to reach them. Consider the set of states that can reach these other accepting states by consuming one input symbol. Consider a new NFA with the other accepting states replaced with this new set of states marked as accepting. The resulting NFA accepts all strings of length no more than k in no more than k states (since we removed at least one other accepting state from a set of k+1 states). This contradicts the induction hypothesis, so no NFA with no more than k+1 states exists to accept all strings of length no more than k+1.

Comment: Case k=1: no transitions means only the empty string is accepted. Otherwise there can be or not loops for every letter, so you get several different languages. Or do you suppose that he NFA has to be complete?

Comment: For the induction step, different first letters could lead to different states. Thus the second state does not have to be equivalent to the start state of an automaton for k. It could accept only part of the strings while others are accepted via different second states.

Comment: @PeterLeupold For the first comment, you're right, looking at what was written I think I had complete DFAs in mind at the time. For the second, different letters leading to different states wouldn't be problematic (I think) but the same letter leading to different states is problematic for the reason you give. I will make some changes based on these comments and see if the answer can be improved enough.

Answer (score 0):

The statement would be true for lengths < k.

For length <= k consider a string w of length k. It is accepted along some path. This path visits k+1 states. Since there are only k distinct states, at least one of them is visited twice. So there is a loop in the path. This loop can be done any number of times. Therefore infinitely many strings are accepted, specifically also inifinitely may strings that are longer than k.